# Building a multithreaded python data pipeline with asyncio

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm somewhat new to asynchronous and multithreaded programming (and Python in general) and I'm trying to build an asynchronous data pipeline which uses multithreading to handle the individual streams.

Effectively, I'd like to build something like this: http://skipperkongen.dk/2016/09/09/easy-parallel-http-requests-with-python-and-asyncio/ but with an open (forever running), asynchronous data stream for each API call. The data from each call will then be placed in a MongoDB collection.

Everything I've tried so far seems to fail for a variety of reasons. Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: AFAIK, you could only do asyncio loop in the main thread. Instead of thread, you may use coroutines which would act similarly to threads but asynchronous and pass information back to the main thread.

Comment: Coroutines run in the same the main thread which waits in an even loop. If you need to run long-running or blocking activities, execute these activities in executor. I did not come across any open source python code on this. If you do, do post the links here.

Comment: As @yoonghm says, you need to concider what you want to do. Are you familiar with how `asyncio` works? You typically use an asynchronous approach if you have many streams with little data to process in each. Combining `asyncio` with threads is only useful if some streams require a lot of processing. And if you do try to use mutliple threads to handle this, you have to be aware of the infamous GIL, the global interpreter lock.

Comment: Thanks for these answers. I did come across some code snippets which use coroutines and an executor. @yoonghm do you mind elaborating a little more on how this would work similarly to parallelism/multithreading?

Comment: Please tell us more about your problem so that we can discuss.